Why is this pipe in my garage filled with concrete?
Any idea why this water pipe going into the ground in my garage next to the furnace and water boiler tank is filled at the upper end? What's its intended use? If I want to use it in a effective way, how to re-open it?


It's not a water pipe. To use it in an effective way, run your car into it and get a big dent in the bumper, rather than blowing up the garage.

Is there only one bollard?

@Huesmann Hm, maybe we're looking at the side of the garage with the back close by towards top left, making it hard to approach the appliances at a dangerous speed from behind the one bollard. But would you recommend adding another one anyway?

What would you intend to use it for ?    You could fabricate a small shelf on top, and use this as an upstand to mount a tool, like a grinder.

@LukeSawczak impossible to say since we can see only a very small area.  Never underestimate the creativity of the very drunk or unskilled driver!

It's just a bollard to protect the gas appliances from your vehicle impacting them.

Yeah, your car repair bills would be the least of your worries if you managed to smash your car into your furnace whilst parking it

Anyone wondering "Why would you ever" also I ask "Do you ever intoxicate yourself".

@civitas And people have been known to mix up gas and brake.

Indeed, but intoxication can derive from many things, including excitement anger and the like. Many people pull into their drive and listen to radio, the internet and talk and text while settling down to start family time and the garage door to roll open and then diverted hit the gas.

OR they have a wet shoe and it slips off the clutch; or the one that I believe is most common is getting distracted and simply lifting off the clutch completely, without realising that the car is still in gear.

All these scenarios can be summed up in two words, “Accidents happen” — or in a similar phrase with a shorter first word.

Bee happens! (It is so short that it does not even suit a comment.)

I had a friend in highschool who managed to drive her boat of a car through the front of a 7-11 because she thought she was in reverse.  Luckily no one was harmed and we could make fun of her about it. There was an incident where I live now and some people were killed in a restaurant due to a similar error. Now such barriers are required by code in parking lots here.

@JimmyJames In my area (Maryland) I have noticed bollards added recently (just the past few months) at a bunch of 7-11s. But I have heard of these types of accidents for years.

@manassehkatz-Moving2Codidact Don't forget the Whole Foods produce section incident in Rockville a few months ago... It made national news.
